# Autoware - Localization in the desert

Tags: localization, navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to improve localization in the desert if LiDAR is unable to do so?

I have Velodyne VLP-16 LiDAR which has a range of 100m (although for matching with ndt map, it does not go beyond 15m for small shrubs). Hence for a location like in Mojave Desert in the link shown below. localization using LiDAR fails.

https://www.google.com/maps/@35.018386,-118.0035916,3a,75y,103.99h,96.18t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s4CipBasQ9E1tIPjEIO0F4g!2e0!7i13312!8i6656

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic, Autoware 1.12.0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354011/autoware---localization-in-the-desert/) by [John272](https://answers.ros.org/users/43273/john272/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

GPS seems to be a good choice, modern multi-band GPS are very good and in the desert, you should have no issues having line of sight with at least 4 satellites. I can't think of a better place to do that!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1